# Why does this question have such a weird edit history?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, revision-history

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2923424/revisions

This question has 6 "post closed" notifications and one reopen notification. How is this possible and why did it happen?

The first close notification is four people, then the same four plus a fifth, then the same five plus a sixth, etc. all the way up to ten people.

Note: This was found using [@Deduplicator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator)'s [query here.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/352917)

**Update:** [@animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [informs me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302943/why-does-this-question-have-such-a-weird-edit-history?noredirect=1#comment236203_302943) that this is a [cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/200235) of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51459/200235).

**Update2:** [@TinyGiant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant) points out that there is a related, [but different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302943/why-does-this-question-have-such-a-weird-edit-history?noredirect=1#comment236208_302943) issue [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8411348/1768232)

Comment: Look at the timestamps.  I smell another race condition here.

Comment: The post was just *that* bad of a question.  Closing it once (or even just 5 times) wasn't enough.

Comment: @Servy Until it got reopened ;)

Comment: we need to close it again :)

Comment: Now you cannot vote to close a post once it has been closed. Possibly, in the past, this was not so and if you were viewing the question before it was closed, it would close it again adding your name to the list of closers. Just a hypothesis.

Comment: @TinyGiant That was never the intended behavior.  It looks like that happened this once as a bug, and since I haven't seen it continue to happen, it was probably fixed a long time ago.

Comment: @Servy, that is what I was hypothesizing. I should have specified that the hypothesized situation was not intended behavior, but a bug that was fixed.

Comment: [Closed with more than five votes?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51459/closed-with-more-than-five-votes)

Comment: @animuson Dang, good catch! Too bad this can't be closed as a cross-site dupe.

Comment: @animuson [What about this question, after the supposed fix?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411348/ampps-as-a-production-server)

Comment: @TinyGiant That's a completely different bug. In that case, the fifth close vote simply didn't trigger the post to be closed at all. All of these bugs have since been fixed, though.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Comment: The page is 404'd now :-(