# Search bug? is:question isaccepted:yes returns 3 results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When I search on Stackoverflow with the following parameters:

```
is:q isaccepted:yes
```

I get three results: [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is:q+isaccepted:yes)

[image: results]

Trying on different browsers (Chrome, IE) I get the same result and seemingly the same questions showing. All the questions are from October 9th 2010.

I realise this is an edge case -- but I'm curious as to how a question can be an accepted answer?

I also tried this on the next two biggest sites in the network ([SuperUser](https://superuser.com/search?q=is%3Aq+isaccepted%3Ayes) and [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/search?q=is%3Aq+isaccepted%3Ayes)) and got the expected 0 results.

Comment: Umm.... that last one doesn't even have an answer...

Comment: @JonClements I know... I thought I'd ask a question not about the 10 million questions milestone for a change around here. :)

Comment: That's a hilarious bug. I wonder how that happened.

Comment: Interestingly (maybe) - extending that query to also include deleted posts returns another three -- all of which are *also* on that date...

Comment: Remnants of a previously "fixed" bug?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67114/stack-overflow-outage and the noted wonkiness implied in some of the answers as a result.

Comment: @Barry `hasaccepted` matches questions which have an accepted answer, and `isaccepted` matches answers which are accepted. So the problem is that `is:q isaccepted:yes` should produce 0 results.

Comment: @Oriol Ahhh yes of course. Sorry brain not quite engaged there..

Comment: This is not a bug in the search per-se, but database inconsistency, since Posts.Id=2 PostId should not be used in the AcceptedAnswerId column.

Comment: Seems to be 2 results now, the answerless one is gone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were exactly 6 such questions in the database (4 deleted), all of which were posted on the 9th of October 2010, so there was probably a bug present on that day that caused some questions to get marked as being accepted answers...

I have updated that field in the database directly.

Comment: Data fixes are the best fixes. :)

Comment: Until one deletes the DB by mistake ;)

Answer (score 19):

This question interested me so I did some digging in SEDE and found that somehow the Question Ids of those questions (3896320,3896444,3896217) have ended up in the `AcceptedAnswerId` column on some other questions:

- [3896490 - JQuery Code Needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896490/jquery-code-needed)
- [3896543 - How to Remove All Proper Subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896543/how-to-remove-all-proper-subsets)

---

From this I would presume that the back end SQL Query being produced by that search is something like this:

```
SELECT [A].*
FROM [Posts] AS [Q]
INNER JOIN [Posts] AS [A] ON ([Q].[AcceptedAnswerId] = [A].[Id])
WHERE [A].[PostTypeId] = 1; -- Type 1 = Question
```

[^ SEDE Link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/353449/show-questions-with-questions-as-their-accepted-answer)

Comment: Speculation for why 2 only show up in SEDE where as 3 show up in the search could be that one of the questions which attributes those other questions as their accepted answer might be deleted (and deleted posts aren't exported into SEDE)

Comment: post history inconsistencies: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302943/why-does-this-question-have-such-a-weird-edit-history

Comment: So, is the consensus that we need a developer to sort this out?

Comment: @cybermonkey yes, someone with direct database access would need to null the column for those two answers or possibly the question OPs would need to select new accepted answers